# Repaying with buying common goods

Tags: economics

If two people share the expenses and person 'A' pays 20 in a supermarket then that person should receive 10 from person 'B' in cash to be fair

If the person 'B' decides to repay instead of cash by buying in a next purchase in a supermarket though should that person buy something that costs 20 as well to be fair?

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward "yes" if both A and B get roughly equal use out of both purchases. Is there some particular reason this seems more complicated?

Comment: If there’s a long gap between the purchasing of the common goods or the common goods are very expensive then interest on the money not paid back may be significant.

Answer (score 2):

This is why accounting (though not double entry accounting) was invented...

To keep things equitable, then **yes**, `Person B` giving $10 cash to `Person A` **or** buying $20 of groceries for the "common pot".

I suggest a simple ledger sheet.  Here's a hypothetical scenario where each person makes two purchases during the month for the "common pot":

```
           A    B
           -    -
Purch #1  $20     
Purch #2  $30
Purch #3       $40
Purch #4       $50
EOM Pymt  $20
EOM Rcvd:     $-20
          ---  ---
          $70  $70

TOTAL SPENT: $20+30+$40+$50 = $140
EQUAL CONTRIBUTIONS: $140/2 = $70
EQUALIZING PAYMENT: $70 - $50 = $20
```

In this case, at EOM (end of month), `Person A` pays $20 to `Person B` to ensure that they both contributed an equal amount.

Clear as mud?